# I keep getting an error when using a spritesheet in python

Tags: python, pygame

I am getting 2 errors when trying to run my code, but there's probably more as this is my first time using spritesheets.
The first error is that when calling for the spritesheet it gives me an error saying I am giving 4 argument when it needs only 3. I seem to only see 3 arguments though. The second error is a 'tuple' object is not callable for this line of code:`(-1*halfSpriteWidth,-1*spriteHeight),(-1*spriteWidth,-1*spriteHeight)])`. Could someone please help me figure this out.

```
class spritesheet:
    def __init__(filename,columns,rows):
        sheet = image.load(filename)
        totalCellCount = columns * rows
        rect = sheet.get_rect()
        spriteWidth = cellWidth = rect.width / columns
        spriteHeight = cellHeight = rect.height / rows
        halfSpriteWidth, halfSpriteHeight = cellCenter = (spriteWidth/2,spriteHeight/2)
        cells = list([(index % columns * spriteWidth, index / columns * spriteHeight,spriteWidth,spriteHeight)for index in range(totalCellCount)])
        handle = list([
            (0,0), (-1*halfSpriteWidth,0),(-1*spriteWidth,0),
            (0,-1*halfSpriteHeight),(-1*halfSpriteWidth,-1*halfSpriteHeight),
            (-1*spriteWidth,-1*halfSpriteHeight),(0,-1*spriteHeight)
            (-1*halfSpriteWidth,-1*spriteHeight),(-1*spriteWidth,-1*spriteHeight)])
        def draw(surface,cellIndex, x,y,handle = 0):
            surface.blit(self.sheet(x + handle[handle][0], y + handle[handle][1]),cells[cellIndex])

player = spritesheet('player.png',4,4)
centerHandle = 4
index = 0
```

Comment: Methods of a class automatically receive an initial argument usually named `self` with is the instance being created — so when you call `spritesheet('player.png',4,4)` this extra argument is being added. Change the init function to `def __init__(self, filename, columns, rows):`.

Comment: what about the tuple error?

Comment: You're missing a comma at the end of `(-1*spriteWidth,-1*halfSpriteHeight),(0,-1*spriteHeight)`.

Answer (score 1):

You totally forgot the `self` argument. Your `__init__` method should be:

```
def __init__(self,filename,columns,rows):
```

and also:

```
def draw(self,surface,cellIndex, x,y,handle = 0):
```

and don't forget that the attributes which should be remembered by the instance also need a `self` before.
You probably want:

```
def __init__(filename,columns,rows):
    self.sheet = image.load(filename)
    self.totalCellCount = columns * rows
    self.rect = self.sheet.get_rect()
    #...
    self.handle = list([
        (0,0), (-1*halfSpriteWidth,0),(-1*spriteWidth,0),
        (0,-1*halfSpriteHeight),(-1*halfSpriteWidth,-1*halfSpriteHeight),
        (-1*spriteWidth,-1*halfSpriteHeight),(0,-1*spriteHeight)
        (-1*halfSpriteWidth,-1*spriteHeight),(-1*spriteWidth,-1*spriteHeight)])
```

and in `draw` also `self.handle` when you refer to the list. By the way, the `list` call also is not needed, square brackets are enough.

The tuple error is due to a missing comma between two tuples in the `self.handle` list:

```
(0,-1*spriteHeight)(-1*halfSpriteWidth,-1*spriteHeight),
                  ^^^ insert comma here
```

Comment: If the answer was helpful, please consider to accept / upvote it. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: The OP can't upvote your answer, so I'll oblige — they can, however accept your answer…